# converting array of string to json object in C#

Tags: c#, json

I have got following scenario where i have a array of strings and i need to pass this data as json object.
How can I convert array of string to json object using DataContractJsonSerializer.

code is :

```
string[] request = new String[2];
string[1] = "Name";
string[2] = "Occupaonti";
```

Comment: If you can use third party libs, you should take a look to [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I would recommend using the Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package, as it makes handling JSON trivial. You could do the following:

```
var request = new String[2];
request[0] = "Name";
request[1] = "Occupaonti";

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
```

Which would produce:

```
["Name","Occupaonti"]
```

Notice that in your post you originally were trying to index into the string type, and also would have received an IndexOutOfBounds exception since indexing is zero-based. I assume you will need values assigned to the Name and Occupancy, so I would change this slightly:

```
var name = "Pooja Kuntal";
var occupancy = "Software Engineer";

var person = new 
{   
    Name = name, 
    Occupancy = occupancy
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
```

Which would produce:

```
{
    "Name": "Pooja Kuntal",
    "Occupancy": "Software Engineer"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple class that should do the job. I took the liberty of using Newtonsoft.Json instead of DataContractJsonSerializer.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] request = new String[2];
            request[0] = "Name";
            request[1] = "Occupaonti";
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tom, output of this would be {"Name","Occupation"}... ?

Comment: No. As Alex Neves pointed out in his own answer (which is more complete than mine), the output of this is `["Name","Occupaonti"]`, which in JSON is an array of items.