# How to use lists and return it as a JSON object?

Tags: c#

I currently have a class ErrorEntity which holds various types of file errors.

```
public class ErrorEntity
{
    public List<string> WordPictureErrors { get; set; }
    public List<string> WordTableErrors { get; set; }
}
```

I have other classes that analyze incoming XML data of the Office files and store the identified errors in the above list.

```
Class IdentifyWordPictureErrors
{
errorEntity.WordPictureErrors.Add($"Picture {desc} not inline");
}

Class IdentifyWordTableErrors
{
errorEntity.WordTableErrors.Add($"Picture {desc} not inline");
}
```

Is this the best approach? Or should I have a single list, that stores all the different types of errors?

```
public List<string> WordDocErrors { get; set; }
```

And how would I return the information from the first class `public class ErrorEntity` as JSON to the client?

And how would I return a single list `public List<string> WordDocErrors { get; set; }` with multiple error objects as JSON?

Thank you!

Comment: There is a question regarding converting an array to JSON that you might find helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671846/converting-array-of-string-to-json-object-in-c-sharp  .. as for i it is a good approach? Generally you don't want to keep a list of errors as strings or in memory. Maybe try to log them somewhere. In a file? In a database? Just some ideas. If you want to create a class that represents errors, maybe look into inheriting from Exception to create your own exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Whether to put all errors in a single list or break the errors up into multiple would depend on your use case and/or what you would like to pass on to the code using your `ErrorEntity` object or want to have written in the serialized json representing the `ErrorEntity` object(s).  One cannot advise on anything more without knowing where you will use the `ErrorEntity` object(s).

Regarding creating a json of the `ErrorEntity` object, you can just serialize it using `System.Text.Json` as per the following example:

```
ErrorEntity errorEntity = new()
{
    WordPictureErrors = new()
    {
        "Picture error 1",
        "Picture error 2"
    },

    WordTableErrors = new()
    {
        "Table error 1",
        "Table error 2"
    }
};

string errorEntityJsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(errorEntity);

// resulting in: {"WordPictureErrors":["Picture error 1","Picture error 2"],"WordTableErrors":["Table error 1","Table error 2"]}
```

You will need to add: `using System.Text.Json;` to your implementation.

The same code will apply if you return a single list of error messages, the `ErrorEntity` class will just have one property instead of two (as per your example).

You can find more information on json serializing and deserializing here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0